# Pandas/numpy array filling

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I´ve a Pandas dataframe that I read from csv and contains X and Y coordinates and a value that I need to put in a matrix and save it to a text file. So, I created a numpy array with max(X) and max(Y) extension.

I´ve this file:

```
fid,x,y,agblongo_tch_alive
2368458,1,1,45.0126083457747
2368459,1,2,44.8996854102889
2368460,2,2,45.8565022933761
2358154,3,1,22.6352522929758
2358155,3,3,23.1935887499899
```

And I need this one:

```
   45.01    44.89 -9999.00    
-9999.00    45.85 -9999.00
   22.63 -9999.00    23.19
```

To do that, I´m using a loop like this:

```
for row in data.iterrows():
    p[int(row[1][2]),int(row[1][1])] = row[1][3]
```

and then I save it to disk using **np.array2string**. It works.

As the original csv has 68 M lines, it´s taking a lot of time to process, so I wonder if there´s another more pythonic and fast way to do that.

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE]? It's not really clear what you're trying to do here

Comment: I think you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640852/pandas-dataframe-with-x-y-coordinates-to-numpy-matrix and then just write the output to a text file using `array2string`

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve with the matrix? The sensible way might be to keep the matrix in memory rather than write to disk.

Comment: if the 68M row are a flattened representation of your matrix, then it's ~8250 points which is already pretty huge.

Comment: I edited the question, I need to write it to disk because I need the file in a specific format, not the matrix itself. I´ll check the solution user3483203.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clarified anything at all for me

Comment: roganjosh, the columns X and y are the coordinates of agblongo_tch_alive values. I need to create this matrix.

Comment: You're assuming that `agblongo_tch_alive` means something to me. It doesn't. But that doesn't mean I can't help with your problem. Googling that gives me nothing. Please give an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); the problem you're trying to tackle is not contained in the context of your actual work.

Comment: It doesn´t matter what agblongo_tch_alive is. I have to put the values in agblongo_tch_alive in a matrix x and y coordinates.

Comment: The user3483203 solution is almost there. However, as my X and Y values are float, and when I convert those values to int I got some duplicates, so pivot doesn´t works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns of your `df` are 'x', 'y', 'value', you can use advanced indexing

```
>>> x, y, value = data['x'].values, data['y'].values, data['value'].values
>>> result = np.zeros((y.max()+1, x.max()+1), value.dtype)
>>> result[y, x] = value
```

This will, however, not work properly if coordiantes are not unique.
In that case it is safer (but slower) to use `add.at`:

```
>>> result = np.zeros((y.max()+1, x.max()+1), value.dtype)
>>> np.add.at(result, (y, x), value)
```

Alternatively, you can create a sparse matrix since your data happen to be in sparse coo format. Using the '.A' property you can then convert that to a normal (dense) array as needed:

```
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> spM = sparse.coo_matrix((value, (y, x)), (y.max()+1, x.max()+1))
>>> (spM.A == result).all()
True
```

**Update**: if the fillvalue is not zero the above must be modified.

Method 1: replace second line with (remember this should only be used if coordinates are unique):

```
>>> result = np.full((y.max()+1, x.max()+1), fillvalue, value.dtype)
```

Method 2: does not work

Method 3: after creating `spM` do

```
>>> spM.sum_duplicates()
>>> assert spM.has_canonical_format
>>> spM.data -= fillvalue
>>> result2 = spM.A + fillvalue
```

Comment: Paul, tks! It´s almost there, however, I cant sum the duplicate values because it will double the corresponding value. Instead of it, I need to delete one of the lines.

Comment: @MauroAssis if all rows with the same coordinates also have the same value and you don't want to count their multiplicity you can actually use Method 1. Because in that case it doesn't matter that the order of assignment is undefined.

Comment: Paul, in fact, I checked and there´s only one duplicated value, so I think I will keep method three. Thank you very much!